# error: cannot convert `double ()(double) throw ()' to `double' in assignment

Tags: c++

Can't figure out why I have these error messages. I am brand new to C++.

```
payroll.cpp: In function `void fGross()':
payroll.cpp:57: error: assignment of function `double round(double)'
payroll.cpp:57: error: cannot convert `double' to `double ()(double)
throw ()' in assignment
payroll.cpp:59: error: cannot convert `double ()(double) throw ()'
to `double' in assignment
payroll.cpp: In function `void fSoc()':
payroll.cpp:65: error: assignment of function `double round(double)'
payroll.cpp:65: error: cannot convert `double' to `double ()(double)
throw ()' in assignment
payroll.cpp:67: error: cannot convert `double ()(double) throw ()'
to `double' in assignment
payroll.cpp: In function `void fFed()':
payroll.cpp:73: error: assignment of function `double round(double)'
payroll.cpp:73: error: cannot convert `double' to `double ()(double)
throw ()' in assignment
payroll.cpp:75: error: cannot convert `double ()(double) throw ()'
to `double' in assignment
payroll.cpp: In function `void fSt()':
payroll.cpp:82: error: assignment of function `double round(double)'
payroll.cpp:82: error: cannot convert `double' to `double ()(double)
throw ()' in assignment
payroll.cpp:84: error: cannot convert `double ()(double) throw ()'
to `double' in assignment
payroll.cpp: In function `void fround()':
payroll.cpp:110: error: invalid operands of types `double ()(double)
throw ()' and `double' to binary `operator+'
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

    double hours, gross, socSec, fedTax, stTax, ins, net;
    double const rate = 16.78;
    double unin = 10.00;
    char d = '$';
    void fGross();
    void fSoc();
    void fFed();
    void fSt();
    void fUnin();
    void fIns();
    void fNet();
    void fround();


int main (void)
{
        cout <<"\n\n\t\tWelcome to the Payroll Program!!!\n\n\n"; 

        cout <<"How many hours did you work this week?\t";
        cin >> hours;
        cout <<"How many children do you have?";
        cin >> ins;

        fGross();
        fSoc();
        fFed();
        fSt();
        fUnin();
        fNet (); 

        cout <<"Payroll Stub:\n\n\t"
             <<"Hours:\t" << hours
             <<"\n\tRate:\t" << rate <<"16.78 $/hr\n\t"
             <<"Gross:\t" << d << gross
             <<"\n\n\tSocSec:\t" << d << socSec
             <<"\n\tFedTax:\t" << d << fedTax
             <<"\n\tStTax:\t" << d << stTax
             <<"\n\tUnion:\t" << d << unin;

        fIns();

        cout <<"\n\tNet:\t" << net <<"\n\nThank you for using the PP!!"
             <<"\n\nEndeavor to have a StarTrek-esque day!";

        return 0;
}    


void fGross()
{
    round = rate * hours;
    fround();
    gross = round;
    return;
}

void fSoc()
{
    round = gross * .06;
    fround();
    socSec = round;
    return;
}

void fFed()
{
    round = gross * .14;
    fround();
    fedTax = round;
    return;

}

void fSt()
{
    round = gross * .05;
    fround();
    stTax = round;
    return;
}

void fIns()
{
    if (ins >= 3)
    {
        ins = 35.00;
        cout << "\n\tIns:\t" << d << ins;
    }
    else
    {
        ins = 0.00;
    }
    return;
}

void fNet()
{
    net = gross - socSec - fedTax - stTax - unin - ins;
    return;
}

void fround()
{
    round = floor((round + .05) * 100);
    return;  
}
```

Comment: you should use better names. Nobody knows what `fSt` or `fNet` is supposed to mean and maybe in a month or so even you wont remember. For example when a function is called `calculateNet` it is obvious what the function does

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard library function named [`round`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/round), declared in `<cmath>`.  Your code expects a global *variable* named `round`, which you appear to have forgotten to declare, so all of the uses of `round` in `fGross`, `fSoc`, etc resolve to the function.  You can't assign anything to a function name, and you can't assign a pointer-to-function (which is what you get when you use a function name on the right-hand side of an assignment) to a floating-point variable.  Hence all the confusing errors.

In order to make the program work, you will need to change the name of the variable `round`; if you simply add the missing declaration, you will just get another error,

```
test.cc:10:12: error: ‘double round’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:326:1: note:
    previous declaration ‘double round(double)’
```

... which does at least give you more of a clue what the problem is.

There are a *lot* of other problems with this code, of which I will only point out the most important three:

- All of the `f`-functions should take arguments and return a value; all of the global variables should be removed. (I suspect this is a near-literal translation of some COBOL, so hopefully that's the next refactor you plan to do, but I must point it out anyway.)
- Computations on money *must* be done using [fixed-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) arithmetic to avoid rounding and underflow problems; the simplest thing, which will work well enough for this kind of program, is to scale everything to an integer number of cents and then use `int64_t` variables; in computations involving interest compounded over many years, or similar, you might want to scale to 100ths or 1000ths of a cent instead.
- `using namespace std` is bad practice and will cause more problems of the type you tripped over.  Write `using std::foo;` for each foo you actually need.